# Render view fragments directly, using thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I am trying to get just a part of the view(fragment) from a template, i just end up getting the following error

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "path/to/template::fragment", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

And this is the current configuration:

```
TemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
resolver.setSuffix(".html");
resolver.setCacheable(false);
engine = new TemplateEngine();
engine.setTemplateResolver(resolver);
```

It soud be possible as it is given as a feature(but using spring-mvc, which I am not):

http://www.thymeleaf.org/whatsnew21.html#spfrag

The site application works using jsp, and the code that is failing looks like this:

```
render("surveys/survey", params,request,response);//This works
render("surveys/survey::surveyBody", params,request,response);//This fails

public static String render(String template,Map<String,?> context,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    IContext iContext = new WebContext(request,response,request.getServletContext(),Locale.US, context);
    return engine.process(template, iContext);
}
```

inside the template there is something like this

```
<div th:fragment="surveyBody">
        <div th:each="field,idx : ${survey.fields}" th:id="${'field_' + field.id}" th:class="${field.type + ' row outter'}">
            <input type='hidden' th:id="${'field_' + field.id + '_id'}" id='field_100_id' value='100' />
            <input type='hidden' th:id="${'field_' + field.id + '_type'}" id='field_100_type' th:value='${field.type}' />
            <input type='hidden' th:id="${'field_' + field.id + '_order'}" id='field_100_order' th:value='${field.obj.order}' />
            <input type='hidden' th:id="${'field_' + field.id + '_outstanding'}" id='field_100_outstanding' value='-1' />
            <h3 th:utext="${field.obj.title[0].title}">title</h3>
            <h4 th:if="${!field.obj.subTitle.isEmpty()}" th:utext="${field.obj.subTitle[0].title}">subtitle</h4>
            <div class="answers row">
                <div th:replace="surveys/questions::${field.type}(${field},${disabled},${idx.index})"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where you want the fragment? And how looks like (code) and the fragment call. Works "normal" sites?

Comment: added some code, but i dont understand the part about "Works "normal" sites?"

Comment: the problem is that I am getting all the other things I don't need such as <body>, <head>,<html>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*th:fragment* is called in template using *th:replace* or *th:include* attributes.

Try to create a clear file (*surveys/surveyfragment*) and write there:

```
<div th:replace="surveys/survey::surveyBody"/>
```

And then call it:

```
render("surveys/surveyfragment", params,request,response);
```

Should work

Comment: I am gonna set this as the answer as it works na dI am gonna use it, but it still seems like an ugly solution to me

Answer (score 0):

I'm here after so many hears because [htmx gives me hope for backend rendering](https://htmx.org/). [especially with tamplates that have fragments](https://htmx.org/essays/template-fragments/)

Turns out it is possible to render just `th:fragment` out of big template file, the `.process` method has overload `final def process(template: String, templateSelectors: java.util.Set[String], context: IContext): String` which can take fragment-name

so `templateEngine.process("showdown", Set("showdown-table"), context)`
worked for me to get only html part of the fragment

Comment: Format your answer accordingly. Use code fences instead of inline code.